# If A:A is more than -500 and less than -400, then sum values in corresponding rows in B

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of locations with corresponding values and need to sum the values for a range of locations.

Example

```
middlePeak       tags
-499             107
-495.5           114
-493.5           163
-490.5           66
```

This list goes on from -499 to -500.

There are thousand of locations that I would like to sum up in bins of 10; -500 to -490, -490 to -480, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on what you need but what do you think about:

setting a binary matrix to determine the interval (400-410  410-420 ....)
the a multiplication matrix to make a simple sum.

In the added picture you can see the binary matrix in the middle (between the starting value and the multiplication matrix). In the formula bar there is a possible formula to determine the first matrix (according to my territorial version of excel)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10>-500)*(A2:A10<=-490),B2:B10)
```

This will sum values in B corresponding to A values with -500 < a <= -490.